# JinternalFrame ActionListener Event

Tags: java, swing

I'm implementing a MVC pattern with Swing the problem i have is how do i know from which `JinternalFrame` has the event come from, i need to know this because i'm closing the appropriate window that is clicked but it's not working.
(i close other windows instead)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    String command = evt.getActionCommand();

    if (command.equals("cancelar")){
        System.out.println("Papitas");
        int lastView = views.size();
        //views.get(lastView - 1 ).closeView();
        //views.get().dispose();
        //System.out.println(evt);
    }

}
```

Comment: give some more explanations.

Comment: Ok, i have a class controller that has a arrayList of views and i add the actionListener to the appropriate view. i know the actionListener is working but i have no way of knowing which Jinternalframe is being clicked

Comment: Swing is an implementation of a MVC paradigm, but favors MV-C, where the model and view are more self contained and the controller deals with providing the information they need to get the job done.  Essentially, I would simply allow the button to close the window it's associated with in a more direct manner (may be using a inner class or by passing a reference of the `JInternalFrame` to the action handler when you construct it - the `Action` API would be useful for this)

Comment: What is the source of the event?

Comment: a button click inside a Jinterternal frame

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to get the source of the event, and then traverse parents until you find the `JInternalFrame` containing the source. The code looks a little like this:

```
Object current = evt.getSource();
while(current instanceof Component){
   if(current instanceof JInteralFrame)
      (JInternalFrame current).dispose();
   current = ((Component) current).getParent();
}
```

Comment: The solution was to cast the evt until i got the view out.                         JRootPane jr = SwingUtilities.getRootPane((Component) evt.getSource());
        view = (VerInforCliente) jr.getParent();